# MyBatis: Connection leak when updateting entity

Tags: mybatis

in my project, I run the following code to create "gap" in the ids:

```
<update id="adjustTransactions">

    SELECT nextval('sq_transaction');

    UPDATE transaction
    SET
        id = id + currval('sq_transaction')
    WHERE transaction.id IN (
        SELECT cdt.id
        FROM transaction cdt
        WHERE cdt.datetime &lt; #{till}
    );

    UPDATE transaction
    SET
        id = id - currval('sq_transaction') + 1
    WHERE transaction.id IN (
        SELECT cdt.id
        FROM transaction cdt
        WHERE cdt.datetime &lt; #{till}
    );
```

problem is that this code ends up with:

**java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected**

Thank for any idea or suggestion why there is a connection leak.

Comment: When does this happen? As in can you provide the stacktrace that shows relevant part of the code invoking the query?

Comment: Try to get sq_transaction nextval from outside the query and pass it as parameter.